# H2 database with Oracle mode failing for row_number() over ( order by cust.id )

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, h2

I am using H2 in-memory database for unit testing of Oracle queries. I have written `SET MODE Oracle` statement.

But, it is failing for below part of oracle query:

```
row_number() over ( order by cust.id ) as CustCount
```

I know this is not allowed in H2 db, but we have set the mode to Oracle. Also, I cannot change the query as prod database is Oracle and H2 db is only for unit testing. So, how to write unit test for this?

**Edit**

The exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT RESULTS.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER[*] BY CUST.ID ) AS CUSTCOUNT,   CUST.ADDRESS1 FROM CUSTOMER) RESULTS WHERE CUSTCOUNT BETWEEN 1 AND 50  "; expected ")"; SQL statement:
SELECT RESULTS.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER[*] BY CUST.ID ) AS CUSTCOUNT,   CUST.ADDRESS1 FROM CUSTOMER) RESULTS WHERE CUSTCOUNT BETWEEN 1 AND 50  [42001-193]
```

Comment: What does "failing" mean - what happens, what error do you get? (What's the thinking behind testing in a different database than you'll deploy on? Why not just test against Oracle? You're putting a lot of faith in the emulation being good enough to reveal any real problems with your code - and clearly there are some discrepancies...)

Comment: H2 simply does not support that. Short of implementing it yourself (and ideally offering that to the H2 project as a patch) there is nothing you can do. It's another example on why using a different DBMS for testing and development is not a good idea

Comment: Ok. So, I will try with Oracle in-memory database for unit testing.